# Можно ли использовать Scanner для ввода значений в GUI?

Tags: java, swing, gui, scanner

Такая проблема, хочу, чтобы при нажатии клавиши объект `gena` перемещался в следующую клетку. После создания переменной типа `int` со сканером

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
int i = scn.nextInt();
```

весь фрейм покрывается черным цветом и закрывается только через диспетчер задач. Как избежать этого?

```java
public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(805, 830);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Gena");
    }
}
class DrawFrame extends JFrame {
    public DrawFrame() {
        add(new DrawComponent());
        pack();
    }
}
class DrawComponent extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        int xWhite = 0;
        int yWhite = 0;
        int widthWhite = 800;
        int heightWhite = 800;

        int blackWidth = 100;
        int blackHeight = 100;

        Rectangle2D whiteScreen = new Rectangle2D.Double(xWhite, yWhite, widthWhite, heightWhite);

        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fill(whiteScreen);
        g2.draw(whiteScreen);

        for(int q = 0; q<4; q++) {
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                Rectangle2D black = new Rectangle2D.Double(xWhite, yWhite, blackWidth, blackHeight);

                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fill(black);
                g2.draw(black);

                xWhite = xWhite + 200;
            }
            xWhite = 0;
            yWhite = yWhite + 200;
        }
        xWhite = 100;
        yWhite = 100;
        for(int q = 0; q<4; q++) {
            for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                Rectangle2D black = new Rectangle2D.Double(xWhite, yWhite, blackWidth, blackHeight);

                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fill(black);
                g2.draw(black);

                xWhite = xWhite + 200;

            }
            xWhite = 100;
            yWhite = yWhite + 200;
        }

        int genaX = 25;
        int genaY = 725;
        int genaWidth = 50;
        int genaHeight = 50;


        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int u = scn.nextInt();
        if(u==8) {
            g2.clearRect(genaX, genaY, genaWidth, genaHeight);
            genaY = 675;
            Rectangle2D gena = new Rectangle2D.Double(genaX, genaY, genaWidth, genaHeight);

            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(gena);
            g2.draw(gena);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<13; i++) {
            Rectangle2D gena = new Rectangle2D.Double(genaX, genaY, genaWidth, genaHeight);

            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(gena);
            g2.draw(gena);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сканер работает с консолью на ввод и вывод, что вы от него хотите добиться? Хоть бы документацию читали, что-ли.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете использовать сканер для ввода значений в `paintComponent()`. Поскольку этот метод вызывается контейнером для того чтобы рисовать внутри окна компонента. И метод `nextInt()` прерывает выполнение программы для ввода следующего значения с консоли.

Есть два вида приложений на Java - одно консольное, другое GUI приложение. В первом случае у вас ничего нет кроме коммандной строки для ввода вывода. Во втором случае вы можете использовать компоненты, которые позволяют вводить и отображать вводимые в них значения, такие как `JTextField`.

При нажатии на клавишу, генерируется событие клавиатуры. Вы можете создать слушателя клавиатуры в вашем компоненте или родительском компоненте и тогда вам придется обрабатывать каждое нажатие клавиши для определения кода нажатой клавиши и вычисления значения.