# Вывод графического окна

Tags: java, swing, for, awt

Имеется данная программа, которая считает координаты по заданным расчётам, затем необходимо вывести в окне окружности по полученным координатам x и y. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось одно после цикла, используя этот же метод? Либо как создать публичный класс Board, чтобы сослаться на него после цикла for? на данный момент выводится множество окон, в каждом из которых рисуется одна окружность по ходу цикла.

```
package com.Project;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Прорамма для расчёта координат точек дуги");
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String decision;

            label:
            {
                System.out.print("Введите количество точек n=");

                float n = num.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Введите значение половины хорды дуги l=");
                double l = num.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Введите значение высоты сегмента круга h=");
                double h = num.nextDouble();
                if (h <= l) {

                    double R = (l * l + h * h) / (2 * h);
                    System.out.println("R=" + String.format("%8.2f", R));
                    double k = Math.sqrt(l * l + h * h);
                    double a = (240 * h * (4 * k - l)) / (Math.PI * (l * l + h * h));
                    System.out.println("a=" + String.format("%8.2f", a));
                    double a1 = 90 - (a / 2);
                    double asekt = (a / 2) / ((n - 1) / 2);
                    double x0 = h - R;
                    double y0 = 0;
                    double x = x0 + (R * (Math.sin((a1 * Math.PI) / 180)));
                    double y = y0 + (R * (Math.cos((a1 * Math.PI) / 180)));

                    double asled;
                    int N;

                    for (N = 0; N < n; N++) {
                        asled = a1 + asekt * N;
                        x = x0 + (R * (Math.sin((asled * Math.PI) / 180)));
                        y = y0 + (R * (Math.cos((asled * Math.PI) / 180)));
                        System.out.println("Для точки " + (N + 1) + "    α=" + String.format("%8.2f", asled) + "   x=" + String.format("%8.2f", x) + "   y=" + String.format("%8.2f", y));


                        double x1 = x*100;
                        double y1 = y*100;

                        class Board extends JPanel {

                            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


                                super.paintComponent(g);
                                paint(g);

                            }

                            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                                g.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
                                int d = (int) x1 ;
                                int f = (int) y1;
                                g.drawOval(d, f, 8, 8);

                            }

                    }

                        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Window");
                        jf.setSize(800, 600);
                        jf.setVisible(true);
                        jf.add(new Board());

                        }

                    System.out.print("Провести расчёт ещё раз y/n? ");
                    while (true) {
                        decision = num.nextLine();
                        switch (decision) {
                            case "y":
                                break label;

                            case "n":
                                System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }

                } else ;
                System.out.println("Введены некорректные данные. Введите значения заново:");
                break label;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы используете сканер для ввода данных? Почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847948/204920).